# Как можно сортировать "Напитки' по пустым массивам

Tags: javascript, массивы, сортировка

Код:

```js
let menu=["Americano","Espresso","Latte","Capucino","Orange","Apple","Cherry","Mango","Green Tee","Black Tee","English Breakdast","Puer"];
let jucie=[];
let coffee=[];
let tee=[];

let sortt=function(a){
    for(let i=0;i<a.length;i++){
        menu.sort()
        console.log(menu)
    }
}
sortt(menu)
```

Comment: По какому принципу, вы собираетесь понимать какая строка, к какому напитку принадлежит?

Comment: По хорошему вы должны хранить напитки с информацией того, к какому типу они принадлежат, а не сортировать их где-то.

Comment: а как это сделать ,можно по конкретнее ?

Comment: а как я задумал это сделать это возможно ?

Comment: Я вот вас и спрашиваю как вы это собираетесь делать. Возможно, но придётся для каждого напитка в ручную приписывать, то к какому типу он принадлежит. Теперь снова вопрос, как вы собираетесь понимать к какому типу напитков принадлежит та или иная строка?

Comment: вот я хочу понять как это сделать ,может в "menu" =["Americano,"Latte"],["Orange","Apple"] и так через "".push[0]"" добавить в каждой категории

Comment: Добавлять мы все умеем :) Опять же, как вы собираетесь **СОРТИРОВАТЬ**?

Answer (score 0):

Почему бы просто не сделать словарь? В общем, можно обойтись и без отдельных (избыточных) переменных, но можно и с ними.

```js
let menu = {
    "coffee": ["Americano", "Espresso", "Latte", "Capucino"],
    "juice": ["Orange", "Apple", "Cherry", "Mango"],
    "tea": ["Green tea", "Black tea", "English Breakdast", "Puer"]
};

// в общем-то избыточные переменные
let juice = menu['juice'];
let coffee = menu['coffee'];
let tea = menu['tea'];

console.log(`Соки: ${juice}`);
console.log(`Кофе: ${coffee}`);
console.log(`Чай: ${tea}`);

// если нужно вывести полный список без группировки
let menu_list = Object.values(menu).reduce((a, c) => c + a, []);
console.log(`Полное меню в списке: ${menu_list}`)
```

Comment: Можно кстати заменить `[]` на `''`, акселератор всё равно превращается в строку.

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете сортировать элементы массива menu с помощью метода `sort`, как вы уже сделали. Однако, этот код не будет разбивать элементы массива `menu` на разные массивы `jucie`, `coffee` и `tee`, так как это не прописано в функции `sortt`.

Чтобы разбить элементы массива menu на три разных массива, вам нужно добавить код, который будет проверять каждый элемент массива menu и определять, к какому типу напитков он относится. Например, элемент `"Espresso"` можно добавить в массив `coffee`, а элемент `"Orange"` можно добавить в массив `jucie`.

```
let sortt = function(a) {
  for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    if (a[i].includes("Tea")) {
      tee.push(a[i]);
    } else if (a[i].includes("Coffee")) {
      coffee.push(a[i]);
    } else {
      juice.push(a[i]);
    }
  }
}

sortt(menu);
console.log(juice); // ["Orange", "Apple", "Cherry", "Mango"]
console.log(coffee); //
```

Comment: Вы предлагаете для каждого напитка, не содержащего ключевого, писать отдельные условие? Может я что-то не так понял? Это ведь полный абсурд.